# hdf5: Check to create group

Tags: c++, hdf5

I would like automatically create a group, if a group does not yet exist. I am however not successfull in checking if the group exists.

#### Failing attempt 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

int main(void)
{
  H5::H5File file("test.h5",H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

  std::string group_name = "/test";

  H5::Group group = file.createGroup(group_name.c_str());

  if ( !file.attrExists(group_name.c_str()) )
    H5::Group group = file.createGroup(group_name.c_str());

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation with

```
$ h5c++ -o test test.cpp
```

Fails because `file.attrExists(name)` always returns `false`. For reference, the error occurs at `createGroup`:

```
... 

#006: H5L.c line 1733 in H5L_link_cb(): name already exists
  major: Symbol table
  minor: Object already exists
```

#### Failing attempt 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

int main(void)
{
  H5::H5File file("test.h5",H5F_ACC_TRUNC);

  std::string group_name = "/test";

  try         { H5::Group group = file.openGroup  (group_name.c_str()); }
  catch (...) { H5::Group group = file.createGroup(group_name.c_str()); }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation with

```
$ h5c++ -o test test.cpp
```

Somehow, the `catch` is not successful, and an error is produced when `openGroup` fails:

```
...

#005: H5Gloc.c line 385 in H5G_loc_find_cb(): object 'test' doesn't exist
  major: Symbol table
  minor: Object not found
```

Comment: What if you omit the '/' in "/test" (the `group_name`)?

Comment: @Walter Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't fix either of the two proposed solutions. Can you explain why you think that removing the first slash would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **attempt 1**, fails because a `H5::Group` is not an attribute, so

```
if ( !file.attrExists(group_name.c_str()) )
```

does not what you thought it does. AFAIK, there is no simpler way to check for the existence of a group than trying to open it. This leads us to

Your **attempt 2** is actually **not failing**, but works (why did you think otherwise?) Unfortunately, HDF5 spits out a lot of error blurb (in addition to throw an exception), but you can suppress that

```
int main(void)
{
  H5::Exception::dontPrint();                             // suppress error messages
  H5::H5File file("test.h5",H5F_ACC_TRUNC);    
  std::string group_name = "/test";
  try         {
    H5::Group group = file.openGroup  (group_name.c_str());
    std::cerr<<" TEST: opened group\n";                   // for debugging
  } catch (...) {
    std::cerr<<" TEST: caught something\n";               // for debugging
    H5::Group group = file.createGroup(group_name.c_str());
    std::cerr<<" TEST: created group\n";                  // for debugging
  }
  H5::Group group = file.openGroup  (group_name.c_str()); // for debugging
  std::cerr<<" TEST: opened group\n";                     // for debugging
}
```

generates

> TEST: caught something
>   TEST: created group
>   TEST: opened group

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed put off by the "error blurb".